# changing the type of id from string to uuid in solr 7.2+

Tags: windows, solr

I have created an example SolrCloud instance using example Settings in Solr 7.2.1 on windows:

```
bin/solr start -e cloud
bin/solr.cmd create -c trans -s 2 -rf 2
```

Then I updated the schema (as most of the data will come from `Postgres` and `SQL Server`:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
"add-field":{
     "name":"trans",
     "type":"string",
     "stored":true,
     "indexed":true},

"add-field":{
     "name":"t",
     "type":"pdate",
     "stored":true,
     "indexed":true},

"add-field":{
     "name":"l",
     "type":"pint",
     "stored":true,
     "indexed":true},

}' http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/schema
```

which results into the following schema:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/schema/fields
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "fields":[{
      "name":"_root_",
      "type":"string",
      "docValues":false,
      "indexed":true,
      "stored":false},
    {
      "name":"_text_",
      "type":"text_general",
      "multiValued":true,
      "indexed":true,
      "stored":false},
    {
      "name":"_version_",
      "type":"plong",
      "indexed":false,
      "stored":false},
    {
      "name":"id",
      "type":"string",
      "multiValued":false,
      "indexed":true,
      "required":true,
      "stored":true},
    {
      "name":"l",
      "type":"pint",
      "indexed":true,
      "stored":true},
    {
      "name":"t",
      "type":"pdate",
      "indexed":true,
      "stored":true},
    {
      "name":"trans",
      "type":"string",
      "indexed":true,
      "stored":true}]}
```

In our case, the ID has the type `uuid`. If I change it I get an error:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "replace-field":{
     "name":"id",
     "type":"uuid",
     "stored":true,
 "indexed":true}
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/schema/fields
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":48},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Can't load schema managed-schema: _root_ field must be defined using the exact same fieldType as the uniqueKey field (id) uses: uuid",
...
```

It does not help to change both the `_root_` and `id` either:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "replace-field":{
     "name":"id",
     "type":"uuid",
     "stored":true,
  },
  "replace-field":{
     "name":"_root_",
     "type":"uuid",
     "stored":true,
      "docValues":false,
      "indexed":true,
      "stored":false}
}
' http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/schema
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":50},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Can't load schema managed-schema: _root_ field must be defined using the exact same fieldType as the uniqueKey field (id) uses: uuid",
```

How do I change the type of the `id` in solr properly?